# Automatically set permission for chrome to permanently store data on local computer

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

I am setting up a Selenium test. The test is performed on chrome in incognito mode. 
The application, once started, tries to store data on the computer, and chrome prompts an alert that request the following permission: "(the domain) wants to permanently store large data on your local computer. [OK] [Cancel]".

How do I automatically set this permission?

Answer (score 1):

I was too lazy to read them all, but if there is that option, you will find it among [list of available chrome switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

Here is example how to use them (this one starts Chrmoe maximized):

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--start-maximized"));
chrome = new ChromeDriver(_chromeservice,capabilities);
```

Comment: yeah, I looked at it before, but you convinced me to take another look. So two iterations and three hours later, I found something that looked like it might work. The surprising thing is, it did work! :)
BTW, the switch is:
**--unlimited-storage**